# No se graba la nueva ubicación del marcador después del OnDragListener

Tags: java, android, firebase

En mi `MapsPublisherActivity.java` el usuario busca una ubicación en `GoogleMaps` y le devuelve el `Latitude` y `Longitude`. Cuando se encuentra dicho sitio se pone allí un marcador. Ahora, quiero  agregar un `OnDragListener` para que si el usuario no está conforme con su ubicación de la búsqueda lo pueda ajustar.

El problema que tengo es que la nueva ubicación no se guarda y se graba la ubicación de la búsqueda... Cómo puedo hacer que se graben el nuevo `Latitude` y `Longitude` después de haber arrastrado el marcador a su nuevo sitio?

Abajo tienen mi código de `MapsPublisherActivity.java`.

Gracias de antemano.

Podría alguien decirme qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? No se está guardando la nueva ubicación del marcador después de arrastrarlo. Solo de la búsqueda.

**MapsActivityPublisher.java**

```
searchView = findViewById(R.id.sv_location);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;

                if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivityPublisher.this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (addressList != null)
                        if (addressList.size() > 0) {
                            address = addressList.get(0);
                            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                            if (marker == null) {
                                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
                            } else {
                                marker.remove();
                                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
                            }
                            dragMarker();
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

                            final String postid = getIntent().getStringExtra("postid");
                            final Button buttonDone = findViewById(R.id.button_done);
                            buttonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                                    reference.child(postid).child("latitude").setValue(address.getLatitude());
                                    reference.child(postid).child("longitude").setValue(address.getLongitude());
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivityPublisher.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Modify search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        CheckEnableGPS();
        fetchLastLocation();
    }

private void dragMarker() {
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Place marker where Event will take place", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            }
        });
    }
```

**Codigo actualizado**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;

                if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivityPublisher.this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (addressList != null)
                        if (addressList.size() > 0) {
                            address = addressList.get(0);
                            latitude = address.getLatitude();
                            longitude = address.getLongitude();
                            latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            if (marker == null) {
                                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
                            } else {
                                marker.remove();
                                latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
                            }
                            dragMarker();
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

                            final String postid = getIntent().getStringExtra("postid");
                            final Button buttonDone = findViewById(R.id.button_done);
                            buttonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                                    reference.child(postid).child("latitude").setValue(latitude);
                                    reference.child(postid).child("longitude").setValue(longitude);

                                    startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivityPublisher.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Modify search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        CheckEnableGPS();
        fetchLastLocation();
    }

private void dragMarker() {
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Place marker where Event will take place", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                    latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                latitude = latLng.latitude;
                longitude = latLng.longitude;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: probaste en el dragend obtener la posicion el marker de la siguiente forma LatLng position = marker.getPosition();? eso te retorna la nueva posicion de el marker

Comment: @zhet y luego qué hago con el ```position``` porque se guarda en ```Firebase``` porque en ```child``` arriba tengo ```address.getLatitude();```. Tendría que meter ```position``` en algún sitio...

Comment: agrega la instancia de firebase al dragend o remplaza el valor en alguna variable global para poder acceder desde cualquier metodo

Comment: Ya funciona tío, muchas gracias. Lo he hecho así ```latLng = marker.getPosition();``` y lo he metido en el ```child``` de Firebase que retorna la ubicacion correcta ```Latitude``` y ```Longitude```. Gracias!

Comment: no hay de que, me alegro que te haya funcionado

Comment: @zhet te puedo preguntar una cosa más?

Comment: Si no te importa te puedo perguntar algo en el chat... [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103220/discussion-between-johnnnn-and-zhet).

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en tu boton done, cuando mandas los datos a Firebase, mandas los datos guardados bajo address y no bajo el drag

Cuando haces esto

```
reference.child(postid).child("latitude").setValue(address.getLatitude());
```

El valor `address.getLatitude()` viene del search y no del drag.

Para solucionar esto crea dos variables, latitud y longitud

```
private double latitud;
private double longitud;
```

Y luego haces

```
latitud = address.getLatitude();
longitud = address.getLongitude();
```

una vez que encontraste por el search esa latitud y longitud.

En el momento del drag, al obtener las nuevas latitudes y longitudes desde el drag, sobreescribi estos valores conlos nuevos

```
private void dragMarker() {
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Place marker where Event will take place", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
               latitud = latLng.getLatitude();
               longitud = latLng.getLongitude();
            }
        });
    }
```

y por ultimo en las referencias pasa ese valor de latitud y longitud que puede ser cualquiera de los dos (tanto search como drag)

```
reference.child(postid).child("latitude").setValue(latitud);
                                    reference.child(postid).child("longitude").setValue(longitud);
```

Comment: Una pregunta, tengo ```Latitude``` y ```Longitude``` del tipo ```Double``` y no ```Long```... Lo cambio, lo dejo y agrego lo que me has dicho tú? Cuál es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Comment: perdon, si es double, lo psue mal, ahi lo cambie

Comment: He creado los dos variables ```latitude``` y ```longitude``` como me has dicho. Luego en ```OnCreate``` he heche ```latitude = address.getLatitude();``` y ```longitude = address.getLongitude();``` Ahora, el llegar al ```OnDragListener``` no me sale el ```getLatitude``` al escribir ```latitude = latLng.getLatitude();``` ni ```getLongitude();``` cuando escribo ```longitude = latLng.getLongitude();``` Que he hecho mal?

Comment: usa latLng.latitude  y latLng.longitude , no recordaba como era y lo puse asi pero deberias obtener la latitud y longitud del objeto LatLng

Comment: Igual es raro que no ande el getLatitude y longitude por que en los metodos que tiene el objeto aparecen https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/cluster/navigation/LatLng

Comment: Vale, y luego el ```dragMarker();``` dónde lo dejo porque sigue dándome solo el ```Latitude``` y ```Longitude``` de la búsqueda? Bueno lo he hecho así ```latLng.latitude;``` y ```latLng.longitude;```

Comment: deberia ir fuera de searchView.setOnQueryTextListener , ponelo debajo de fetchLastLocation();

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103178/discussion-between-johnnnn-and-gaston-saillen).

Comment: Hablamos en el chat un momento?

Comment: Acabo de subir el código actualizado con los cambios, pero sigue sin guardar el nuevo Latitude y Longitude. Hay algún error?

Comment: Que es lo que hace en cambio ?

Comment: No hay ningún cambio, sigue sin guardarse el Latitude y Longitude. He subido los cambios que le he hecho al código, mira a ver si algo he hecho mal...